# ¿Cómo extraer R-cuadrado y p-value de una regresión (lm)?

Tags: r

He realizado algunos modelos lineales (regresiones). Obtuve el resumen del modelo pero me gustaría extraer los valores de `R-squared` y `p-value`, para incluirlos luego en una gráfica

```
mod1 <- lm(SLA ~ Cobertura, data = data_total)
summary(mod1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`summary()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/summary) además de mostrar datos por pantalla, en el caso de un modelo lineal como parámetro de entrada, retorna un objeto de la clase `"summary.lm"`,en sus atributos hay mucha información útil:

```
p.value <- summary(mod1)$coefficients[2,4] 
r.squared <- summary(mod1)$r.squared
```